# Create folder link in FTP

Tags: ftp, symbolic-link

I have FTP with directories and I want to create a symbolic link in the FTP to other directory in the FTP.

I have directory `B` in path `/A/B`, and I want to create directory `/C` that is symbolic link to `/A/B`. When `B` and `C` are in the FTP.

How can I do that? (You can answers in Linux or Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done via the FTP protocol, as links are parts of a filesystem and not the FTP protocol. However, if you can log in to a shell, for example via SSH, you can do it with the `ln` command (it's a standard linux command, as well as on many other systems): `ln -s target/directory linkname`. In your case, this would be:

```
ln -s A/B C
```

The above presumes that your CWD is the FTP root. You want to doublecheck with `pwd` that you are referencing the correct folders before executing the command, as the filesystem root and the FTP root are likely to be different.

Comment: *"as links are parts of a filesystem and not the FTP protocol"*: This explanation does not make sense. File are also part of file system, not FTP protocol, yet you can manipulate them over FTP.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it looks looks you completely misunderstand the sentence

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard FTP command to create symlink.

Some servers (for example [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/FTP.html)) support non-standard command:

```
SITE SYMLINK target source
```